# Check if edit box is using this format

Tags: delphi

I want to check and see if the TEdit.text is in this format  123/45/678  When text was entered
Thus ###/##/###

any simple way to do this?
thanks

Comment: A side note, you can use a `TMaskEdit` control and set the `EditMask` so the input can be validated by the control.

Comment: Check that the string has 9 chars, 4 and 7 are / and that the rest are digits.

Comment: David meant *10* chars, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function CheckStringWithMask(const Str,Mask:String):Boolean;
var
 i:Integer;
begin
  Result := true;
  if length(str)=length(Mask) then
    begin
    i := 0;
    While Result and  (I < Length(Str)) do
      begin
      inc(i);
      Result := Result and (Str[i] <> '#')
                and ((Mask[i] ='#') and (CharInSet(Str[i],['0'..'9']))
                or (Str[i]=Mask[i]));
      end;
    end
  else Result := false;
end;
```

Comment: It might be better to use [`CharInSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.CharInSet) function to check if an input char is a number. Also might be better to break the loop when you'll know the result is False. [+1]

Comment: `CheckStringWithMask('#23/45/678','###/##/###');` evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your mask is so simple that it only has # and / it's easy to write a test function:

```
function MatchesMask(const Text, Mask: string): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;

  if Length(Text)<>Length(Mask) then
    exit;

  for i := 1 to Length(Text) do
    case Mask[i] of
    '#':
      if (Text[i]<'0') or (Text[i]>'9') then
        exit;
    else
      if Text[i]<>Mask[i] then
        exit;
    end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

A variation on [@David Heffernan's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14828107/297408):

```
function MatchesMask(const Text, Mask: string): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := (Length(Text) = Length(Mask));

  if not Result then Exit;

  i := 0;
  while Result and (i < Length(Text)) do begin
    Inc(i);
    case Mask[i] of
    '#':
       Result := (Text[i] >= '0') and (Text[i] <= '9');
    else
       Result := (Text[i] = Mask[i]);
    end;
  end;    
end;
```